# Getting BYE JavaMail Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out while reading mails via apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, jakarta-mail, imap

Getting the following exception while reading mails via Apache camel .

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: * BYE JavaMail Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:738)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.ensureIsConnected(MailConsumer.java:520)
at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.poll(MailConsumer.java:94)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The camel code is as follows

```
from("imaps://" + emailUserName + "@" + emailHost + ":" + emailPort
                + "?password=" + emailPassword
                + "&delete=true"
                + "&consumer.delay=" + delay
                + "&mail.imap.ssl.trust=" + emailHost
                + "&disconnect=false&closeFolder=false")
```

Comment: The exception probably means that the client didn't send any commands for a while, and then the server closed the connection. If that's reasonable from your point of view, fine. If not, you have to show a protocol log to analyse this further.

Comment: I am getting this exception from client side only .

Comment: You mean that the client receives a `BYE` that the server did not send?

Comment: That is what coming in the exception logs . Please see the logs I have posted in the description.

Comment: SocketTimeoutException on protocolConnect probably means it couldn't connect to the server, possibly due to a firewall.

Comment: While trying to connect to the server, the client sends a command and then gets a timeout while waiting for the response.  Usually this is because the server dropped the connection without sending a BYE response to the client, so JavaMail just "fakes it".  Sometimes this happen is you make a plain text connection on an SSL port, but that doesn't seem to be what you're doing.  The[JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) would help, but I have no idea how to enable that through camel.